# How to select first/previous/next/last row in wpf DataGrid

Tags: wpf, datagrid

I've got a WPF application which contains a standard DataGrid showing a lot of data.

Now I want to add buttons to select the next/first/previous/last row.

Is there a way to tell the DataGrid to change the selection for me?

I tried to use

```
private void SelectNext_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  datagrid.MoveFocus(new TraversalRequest(FocusNavigationDirection.Next));
}
```

but it does not work for me (does not change the selected item, sets just the cell focus to the first item instead).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
private void SelectNext_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   if (dataGrid.Items.Count - 1 > datagrid.SelectedIndex)
   {
      datagrid.SelectedIndex++;
   }
}

private void SelectPrevious_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   if (dataGrid.SelectedIndex > 0)
   {
      datagrid.SelectedIndex--;
   }
}

private void SelectFirst_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   dataGrid.SelectedIndex = 0;
}

private void SelectLast_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   dataGrid.SelectedIndex = dataGrid.Items.Count - 1;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

If you fill your datagrid with a datasource by databinding, you can do that

Example of button "next"

```
private void btnNext_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
        ICollectionView view = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(yourDataSource);
        view.MoveCurrentToNext();
}
```

The interface `ICollectionView` has all the methods you need for moving the current item

In XAML remember also to set

```
<DataGrid .....     IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" >
```

Comment: Nice one! Is there a way to check if the current item is the last one, so I can disable the button to move to the next item?

Comment: Something like that is at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.collectionview.iscurrentafterlast.aspx

Comment: Looks like there is no way to disable the button. I just would know I'm at the end (or beginning) after the fact and could either go back or wrap.

Comment: I did some search in Internet. If the following returns true then you are not on the last item. I hope this helps

view.CurrentPosition < view.Cast<Object>().Count() - 1;